# Retrieve all username except admin

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-membership

I am working with this particular system. At admin page, of course as the admin, he can views all the users of the system. To view all users, I use this code in order to retrieve all user in db.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
       BindGridview();
   }
}

protected void BindGridview()
{
   gvDetails.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers();
   gvDetails.DataBind();
}
```

The problem now is, the grid view shows all the users and the admin too. How can I prevent the gridview to show admin's email and username?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You would do something like this:

```
using System.Linq;

protected void BindGridview() 
{ 
   var users = from user in Membership.GetAllUsers()
                    where user.UserType != "Admin"
                    select user;

   gvDetails.DataSource = users; 

   gvDetails.DataBind(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it gives me this error : Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection'.
'Where' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'user'.

Comment: The query should be  from MembershipUser user in Membership.GetAllUsers()   // Reference: http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2009/01/15/Using-LINQ-with-unfriendly-collections.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you need to have query which should retrieve only the normal(specific) users and not all the users with admins users and for that your database should have a field with the User type column which should be having Id key referencing from User Type Master Table. At time of retrieval you only need to pass the select statement specific which type of user you wants to retrieve.